# Bootstrap collapse effect doesn't work properly

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am not really good at bootstrap. Can someone help me why the collapse effect isn't working?

This is my link I got from bootstrap.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This is my HTML code. As you can see, I have the data-toggle and the aria-expanded so I don't know what I'm missing here.

```
<div id="accordion">

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            Collapsible Group Item #1
            </button>
        </h5>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 
            3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum 
            eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla 
            assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt 
            sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, 
            raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            Collapsible Group Item #2
            </button>
        </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 
            3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum 
            eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla 
            assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt 
            sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, 
            raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

But the collapse effect doesn't work.

Comment: `@Alucard` Change position of **bootstrap.min.js** this file should bottom of **popper.min.js** file so after arranging like 1- **jquery**, 2-**popper.min.js** and last one is **bootstrap.min.js** then collapse will work.

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery** must come first, then **Popper.js** then **Bootstrap.js**, and then our JavaScript plugins if need.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container p-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div id="accordion">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">Collapsible Group Item #1</button>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 
          3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum 
          eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla 
          assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt 
          sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, 
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">Collapsible Group Item #2</button>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 
          3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum 
          eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla 
          assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt 
          sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, 
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```